# td with width 100% inside div with position absolute

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Behavior of code snippet is different in `Chrome 51.0.2704.103` and `Firefox 47.0.1`.

Please explain why this happens. Where behavior is correct, where not and why you think so. Thanks.

```css
div,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
}
.w100Pc {
  width: 100%;
}
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Modal dialog header</div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="w100Pc">rest of space column</td>
      <td class="nowrap">content based width column</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div>Here goes main content what should stretch "container" width</div>
  <div>Modal dialog footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What were you expecting to have happen?

Comment: Main idea is to divide space inside of modal dialog into two columns. Space for second column calculated relatively of its inner content. Space for first column is remaining width of modal dialog

Comment: In new code snippet more clearly expressed intention. I just not frontend developer. What you suggest? IE10+ and other evergreen browsers

Comment: I'd suggest flexbox.

Comment: Internally we not use flexbox, i think, because `caniuse` not suggest it. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox Need support of IE10+

Answer (score 1):

Browser render the code differently i guess it's because they follow different standards, i think Firefox is rendering the code currently in you example and to make it look the same in both browsers just add `display:block;`

```css
div,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.w100Pc {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  font-family:'Times New Roman';
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left:200px">
  <table class="w100Pc">
    <tr>
      <td class="w100Pc">
        w100Pc
      </td>
      <td>buttons</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```